# Heap Size Bigger than Used Heap Size

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management

I am trying to minimize the memory use of my java application as much as possible. I would like to know what people think with the statistics shown below. I can't understand why the heap size is much bigger than the used heap size and how I would go about decreasing it.

Please refer to the information below.

I am using Visual VM. Also you can see that Used Heap size increases by time slowly.

[image]

Second Run, you can see the heap size decreasing for some reason.

[image]

Comment: What kind of application is this?

Comment: Multi-threaded application that crawls the web. It has running cycles with linked lists that stores crawling sources executes them and once finishes clears the list and repeats.

Comment: At guess, it's because you have a lot of Buffered stream(s) processing your requests.

Comment: well it still wouldn't explain why there is an extreme amount of unused data on the heap.

Comment: Are you closing your Streams? Are you sure? I can't see your code, and neither can anyone else here.

Comment: I put a 5 second timeout on all streams, so automatically they should close right?

Comment: How did you put a 5 second timeout on all streams?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, the streams are done through the threads with the death of a thread which can be shown on the graph above there would be the death of a stream hence you could expect fluctuations of the memory heap. What I am concerned about is the huge amount of unused data.

Comment: If you don't close the streams, and deallocate them correctly then they (and their buffers) will not be collected.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I suppose by streams you mean HTTP requests and I have connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

Comment: No. That will not close the streams once they have connected and read data.

Comment: The underlying streams will eventually close, but not the Buffer(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch with a death of a thread any objects declared and defined in it are deallocated correct? All this is done through threads so I don't see why the garbage collector would keep them around. I also update a screenshot after longer run of my code.

Comment: No. [Clean up after yourself](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Comment: Heap memory may get fragmented over time, so it may happen, that there is enough space for an allocation in total but no single free piece is big enough and the heap has to be enlarged.

Comment: @Henry In Java with a compacting GC? How exactly would that happen? That said if a stream gets GCed it *will* deallocate all memory it had, so while it may take longer than necessary if you don't do it at the right point you won't leak any memory.